# PHP, Image rezise throws errors for uppercase JPG files

Tags: php, image, resize

I have a PHP script which I call on the fly to realize images.

This script works find for everything I have used apart from uppercase JPG files, I have since uploaded these and converted the extension to lowercase but this is still throwing errors after being re-sized.

Has anyone encountered this or managed to fix this problem?

The Script I am using:

```
<?php
$source_image = $_GET["i"];
$width = $_GET["w"];
$height = $_GET["h"];
$quality = $_GET["q"];
$crop = $_GET["c"];
// If the source image isn't an image seriously we got issues
if( ! $image_data = getimagesize( $source_image ) ){
    die( "Whoa can't get the image size of the original?" );    
}
// Is it a gif, jpg or png. Sorry anything else probably not worth it.
switch( strtolower($image_data['mime']) ){
case 'image/gif':
    $get_func = 'imagecreatefromgif';
    $suffix = ".gif";
    break;
case 'image/jpeg';
    $get_func = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
    $suffix = ".jpg";
    break;
case 'image/png':
    $get_func = 'imagecreatefrompng';
    $suffix = ".png";
    break;
}


// Setup some variables
$img_original = call_user_func( $get_func, $source_image );
$old_width = $image_data[0];
$old_height = $image_data[1];
$new_width = $width;
$new_height = $height;
$src_x = 0;
$src_y = 0;
$current_ratio = round( $old_width / $old_height, 2 );
$desired_ratio_after = round( $width / $height, 2 );
$desired_ratio_before = round( $height / $width, 2 );

// Some people don't want to upscale images. I don't care
// Uncomment if you want crash out and not upscale.

if( $old_width < $width || $old_height < $height )  {
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg( $img_original, NULL, $quality );
}




/**
  * If the crop option is left on, it will take an image and best fit it
  * so it will always come out the exact specified size.
  */
if( $crop )
{
/**
  * create empty image of the specified size
  */
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $width, $height );

/**
  * Landscape Image
  */
if( $current_ratio > $desired_ratio_after )
{
$new_width = $old_width * $height / $old_height;
}

/**
  * Nearly square ratio image.
  */
if( $current_ratio > $desired_ratio_before && $current_ratio < $desired_ratio_after )
{
if( $old_width > $old_height )
{
$new_height = max( $width, $height );
$new_width = $old_width * $new_height / $old_height;
}
else
{
$new_height = $old_height * $width / $old_width;
}
}

/**
  * Portrait sized image
  */
if( $current_ratio < $desired_ratio_before )  {
    $new_height = $old_height * $width / $old_width;
}

    /**
      * Find out the ratio of the original photo to it's new, thumbnail-based size
      * for both the width and the height. It's used to find out where to crop.
      */
    $width_ratio = $old_width / $new_width;
    $height_ratio = $old_height / $new_height;

    /**
      * Calculate where to crop based on the center of the image
      */
    $src_x = floor( ( ( $new_width - $width ) / 2 ) * $width_ratio );
    $src_y = round( ( ( $new_height - $height ) / 2 ) * $height_ratio );
    }
    /**
      * Don't crop the image, just resize it proportionally
      */
else {
    if( $old_width > $old_height ){
        $ratio = max( $old_width, $old_height ) / max( $width, $height );
    }else{
        $ratio = max( $old_width, $old_height ) / min( $width, $height );
    }

    $new_width = $old_width / $ratio;
    $new_height = $old_height / $ratio;

    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $new_width, $new_height );
}

/**
  * Where all the real magic happens
  */
imagecopyresampled( $new_image, $img_original, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height );

/**
  * Save it as a JPG File with our $destination_filename param.
  */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg( $new_image, NULL, $quality );

/**
  * Destroy the evidence!
  */
imagedestroy( $new_image );
imagedestroy( $img_original );

?>
```

Comment: Can You post those errors here ?

Comment: Its when you view the image, so when you put an image on the page you will link to the above script define the path and width etc and it will usually display the image fine but with images with an uppercase extension or one coverted to lowercase up upload you will get "This image can't be displayed it contains errors" so thats what I mean by errors.

Comment: @Sam remove/comment the header part, you should get the error message

Comment: Its just giving white space if you comment the header out.

Comment: @Sam have you checked the source (ctrl+u) ?

Comment: Nope nothing in the source, this is confusing now.

Comment: @Sam make sure there is no spaces before `<?php`

Comment: No spaces :/ just went over the code again couldn't spot anything out of place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem I am having is related to the PHP functions I was using for resizing, I used this similar script: http://shiftingpixel.com/2008/03/03/smart-image-resizer/

And didn't get any problems and that script uses the GD library so its a bit quicker etc.

Thanks for trying to help Hamza.